# Custom css on google web translate

Tags: html, css

i was having problem with creating custom css for google web translate. here's my code

```
<select onchange="doGTranslate(this);">
    <option value="">Select Language</option>
    <option value="id|ar">Arabic</option>
    <option value="id|zh-CN">Chinese (Simplified)</option>
    <option value="id|zh-TW">Chinese (Traditional)</option>
    <option value="id|en">English</option><option value="id|id">Indonesian</option>
    <option value="id|ja">Japanese</option><option value="id|ms">Malay</option></select>
    <div id="google_translate_element2" ></div>
```

javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit2() {new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'id',autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element2');}
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit2"></script>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('6 7(a,b){n{4(2.9){3 c=2.9("o");c.p(b,f,f);a.q(c)}g{3 c=2.r();a.s(\'t\'+b,c)}}u(e){}}6 h(a){4(a.8)a=a.8;4(a==\'\')v;3 b=a.w(\'|\')[1];3 c;3 d=2.x(\'y\');z(3 i=0;i<d.5;i++)4(d[i].A==\'B-C-D\')c=d[i];4(2.j(\'k\')==E||2.j(\'k\').l.5==0||c.5==0||c.l.5==0){F(6(){h(a)},G)}g{c.8=b;7(c,\'m\');7(c,\'m\')}}',43,43,'||document|var|if|length|function|GTranslateFireEvent|value|createEvent||||||true|else|doGTranslate||getElementById|google_translate_element2|innerHTML|change|try|HTMLEvents|initEvent|dispatchEvent|createEventObject|fireEvent|on|catch|return|split|getElementsByTagName|select|for|className|goog|te|combo|null|setTimeout|500'.split('|'),0,{}))
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
```

the css

```
<style>
 #google_translate_element2 {
display:none!important;
}
</style>
```

i was trying to make like this
[by flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o1RY.png)

or this one
[by language id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wt1J8.png)

please help me, thank you

Comment: What is the problem? And does this have anything to do with Google Translate (as mentionned in the title), or is it just a CSS question?

Comment: this is google web translate sir, and i want to change default style using css